# Restarting code when user clicks message dialogue "ok" button

Tags: c#

I am trying to spice up my code for a simple number guessing game I am making.  Once the user guesses the proper number a message dialogue box pops up telling him he is a winner.  That message dialogue box has one button named "ok" when I click it I am taken back to the form.

Instead I would like it to restart the code so that a new random number is generated.  Is this possible or do I need to manually revert the code back to its default state within the winner code area?

Here is my code now:

```
    private void btnEval_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // increment the counter to be displayed later
        howManyClicks++;



        // main decision conditions, ensures something is entered
        if (txtNum.Text != "")
        {
            // user input number
            double num = double.Parse (txtNum.Text);

            if (randomNumber > num)
            {
                // if too low
                this.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                lblMain.Text = "TOO LOW!";
                lblReq.Text = "please try again";
                txtNum.Clear ();
                txtNum.Focus ();

            }
            else if (randomNumber < num)
            {
                // if too high
                this.BackColor = Color.Red;
                lblMain.Text = "TOO HIGH!";
                lblReq.Text = "please try again";
                txtNum.Clear ();
                txtNum.Focus ();
            }
            else
            {
                // correct
                this.BackColor = Color.Green;
                lblMain.Text = "CORRECT!";
                lblReq.Text = "well done";
                MessageBox.Show ("You are right!! It took you " + howManyClicks + " guesses", "You are a WINNER!!",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
                txtNum.Clear ();
                txtNum.Focus ();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show ("You must enter a vaild number! Please try again.", "ERROR",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
            txtNum.Clear ();
            txtNum.Focus ();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, your "game state" (`howManyClicks`, `randomNumber`, ...) is stored in instance variables of the form. Thus, you have the following options:

---

Extract the game state into its own class and keep only a reference to an instance of this class in your form:

```
GameState state;
```

When you start or restart the game, just assign a `new GameState()` to `state` and reset the user interface elements of the form.

---

Alternatively, you can close and reopen the form. Your main loop could look something like this:

```
while (true) {
    var form = new GameForm();
    var result = form.ShowDialog(); // waits until the form as been closed

    if (result == DialogResult.Cancel) {
        break;  // The user wants to stop playing
    }
}
```

In your game form, when the `OK` button is clicked, you set [`Me.DialogResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult.aspx) to `DialogResult.OK` and then close the form. The outer loop will automatically reopen a new, empty game form.

Answer (score 1):

Simply make function for this code.

Select all the code and then right click on it, select second option: `Refactor`

Select suboption: `Extract a method`.

You can give name for this public method.

Then you can call this method from anywhere,( as you have mentioned restart the code).